# How to Compare two Object of Data's in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

Am having some id's in my "var " . That id's are all present in a Static data which is having both id with names . What i'm trying to do is i have to find out the name's of my id's and print the name's alone . I'm trying with many Underscore js method's but failed . Can some one clarify/Suggest me pls .

```js
 var CatePeri =[];
 var cate =[];
// var CateName=[];

   $scope.getCategories = function() {
      for (var i = 0 ; i < mainSteps.length; i++) {
          for (var j = 0; j<mainSteps[i].steps.length; j++) {                 
              var CatePeri= mainSteps[i].steps[j].category;
               cate.push(CatePeri);
        // var CateName =_.findWhere(mainSteps[i].category, cate);
        // var CateName =_.where(mainSteps[i].category, cate);
              }
         }
           return cate; // It return Id's Now
                        // But i have to Return the name's of that id's
```

Here

```
var CatePeri is having Whole Category id's with Names,
      var cate is having Category id's alone,
```

Instead of returning id's i need to Return their names .

Answer (score 1):

```js
 var CatePeri =[];
 var cate =[];
// var CateName=[];

   $scope.getCategories = function() {
      for (var i = 0 ; i < mainSteps.length; i++) {
          for (var j = 0; j<mainSteps[i].steps.length; j++) {                 
              var CatePeri= mainSteps[i].steps[j].category;
               cate.push(CatePeri);
        // var CateName =_.findWhere(mainSteps[i].category, cate);
        // var CateName =_.where(mainSteps[i].category, cate);
              }
         }
           return _.pick(_.values(cate), 'name'); // It return Id's Now
                        // But i have to Return the name's of that id's
```

Comment: Just now i tried that, it return's { } ...Empty Object

Comment: What is the structure of cate. Any details?

Comment: ["1","4","2","3","5"]

Comment: ok. So cate is an array like ["1","4","2","3","5"] and what is the output expected. 14235 ? If I am guessing right? or is each entry in cate an object having 'name' property.

Comment: No No No !!!!!!!   in that CarePeri , it have [id :1,Name : sample , id : 2 , Name : demo .... ] like that it have .. Now Cate returns only 1,2,3,...like that instead of that i have to return that id names like sample,demo ..etc

Comment: _.map(cate, function(value ,key){
return value.Name;
})

Comment: What does it mean value here ?

Answer (score 0):

I assumed,you Have a static JSON like below

```
var staticJson ={
         id:'5rtf567',
         name:'S'
           }
```

Use underscore.js `_.where` option like,

```
   // If you have the multiple object to find out the name put it the below code in `for` loop and try it
   var nameOfId  = _.where(staticJson ,{id:staticJson.id}
   console.log('If you Want Whole Object',angular.toJson(nameOfId));    
   console.log('If you Want Name',angular.toJson(nameOfId.name));
```